# Rename properties in an indefinite nested array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

I have this Array

```js
[
  {
    id: "2b077c3c-9d3a-48ba-9217-f5d3d28c2dfc",
    description: "Response #1",
    user: { id: "3ae5967a-cdfa-4047-aff9-b0c95d2d4da4", name: "User" },
    responses: [
      {
        id: "69442cb1-7de7-4f2d-9c8b-d6689fa1d007",
        description: "Response #2",
        media: "b414e44f-7371-4cef-b0d9-d240e55b0ed1.jpg",
        user: { id: "3ae5967a-cdfa-4047-aff9-b0c95d2d4da4", name: "User" }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: "d8271620-9937-4815-bd35-acad62d85f53",
    description: "Response #3",
    user: { id: "3ae5967a-cdfa-4047-aff9-b0c95d2d4da4", name: "User" },
    responses: [
      {
        id: "05acce0a-8f7e-4ccd-9bbc-3337e4faa8ca",
        description: "Response #4",
        user: { id: "3ae5967a-cdfa-4047-aff9-b0c95d2d4da4", name: "User" }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

And I want to rename the properties to

```js
[
  {
    id: "2b077c3c-9d3a-48ba-9217-f5d3d28c2dfc",
    name: "User — Response #1",
    children: [
      {
        id: "69442cb1-7de7-4f2d-9c8b-d6689fa1d007",
        name: "User — Response #2"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: "d8271620-9937-4815-bd35-acad62d85f53",
    name: "User — Response #3",
    children: [
      {
        id: "05acce0a-8f7e-4ccd-9bbc-3337e4faa8ca",
        name: "User — Response #4",
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I've tried to solve this with map and recursion

```js
function mapArray(array) {
  return array.map(({ id, description, user: { name }, responses }) => {
    if (responses !== undefined) {
      return mapArray(responses);
    }

    return {
      id,
      name: `${name} — ${description}`,
      children: responses
    };
  });
}
```

But it the array becomes nested and the children is `undefined`.

```js
[
  [
    {
      id: '69442cb1-7de7-4f2d-9c8b-d6689fa1d007',
      name: 'User — Response #2',
      children: undefined
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      id: '05acce0a-8f7e-4ccd-9bbc-3337e4faa8ca',
      name: 'User — Response #4',
      children: undefined
    }
  ]
]
```

Please note that the `responses` have indefinite depth.

Where did I mess up? Thanks

Comment: should you not do `responses = mapArray(responses)` inside your if condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close. Only 1 line change inside the if conditions should fix it.

```
function mapArray(array) {
  return array.map(({ id, description, user: { name }, responses }) => {
    if (responses !== undefined) {
      responses = mapArray(responses);
    }

    return {
      id,
      name: `${name} — ${description}`,
      children: responses
    };
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Samridh diagnosed the issue and gave you a useful fix.  If you're looking for a slightly more declarative version of the same idea, you could write the function like this:

```js
const mapArray  = (array) => array .map (
  ({id, description, user: {name}, responses}) => ({
    id,
    name: `${name} - ${description}`,
    ...(responses ? {children: mapArray (responses)} : {})
  })
)

const input = [{id: "2b077c3c-9d3a-48ba-9217-f5d3d28c2dfc", description: "Response #1", user: {id: "3ae5967a-cdfa-4047-aff9-b0c95d2d4da4", name: "User"}, responses: [{id: "69442cb1-7de7-4f2d-9c8b-d6689fa1d007", description: "Response #2", media: "b414e44f-7371-4cef-b0d9-d240e55b0ed1.jpg", user: {id: "3ae5967a-cdfa-4047-aff9-b0c95d2d4da4", name: "User"}}]}, {id: "d8271620-9937-4815-bd35-acad62d85f53", description: "Response #3", user: {id: "3ae5967a-cdfa-4047-aff9-b0c95d2d4da4", name: "User"}, responses: [{id: "05acce0a-8f7e-4ccd-9bbc-3337e4faa8ca", description: "Response #4", user: {id: "3ae5967a-cdfa-4047-aff9-b0c95d2d4da4", name: "User"}}]}]

console .log (mapArray (input))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

Comment: This is neater. Samridh version still left the object to exist even if it doesn't have any value and left an `undefined`. Thank you scott!

Comment: Note though that there's also a strong argument in favor of a consistent interface.  While the `undefined` could well be problematic, you might also consider something like `children: (responses ? mapArray (responses) : [])` to include an empty array in that case.  It might save much special-casing in later steps.

Answer (score 0):

Might me a little ugly but is an alternate.
Also `Array.map()` returns an array so it is obvious for it to be nested.

```js
var obj = [
  {
    id: "2b077c3c-9d3a-48ba-9217-f5d3d28c2dfc",
    description: "Response #1",
    user: { id: "3ae5967a-cdfa-4047-aff9-b0c95d2d4da4", name: "User" },
    responses: [
      {
        id: "69442cb1-7de7-4f2d-9c8b-d6689fa1d007",
        description: "Response #2",
        media: "b414e44f-7371-4cef-b0d9-d240e55b0ed1.jpg",
        user: { id: "3ae5967a-cdfa-4047-aff9-b0c95d2d4da4", name: "User" }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: "d8271620-9937-4815-bd35-acad62d85f53",
    description: "Response #3",
    user: { id: "3ae5967a-cdfa-4047-aff9-b0c95d2d4da4", name: "User" },
    responses: [
      {
        id: "05acce0a-8f7e-4ccd-9bbc-3337e4faa8ca",
        description: "Response #4",
        user: { id: "3ae5967a-cdfa-4047-aff9-b0c95d2d4da4", name: "User" }
      }
    ]
  }
];

var newObj = [];

obj.forEach(({ id, description: name, user: children }) => {
  newObj.push({ id, name, children: [children] });
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(newObj, null, 2));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```